# STRANGE IF-ELSE BEHAVIOR : IF-ELSE both loop executing

Tags: java, android, if-statement

i was using If-Else Statement in my validation function.
I had a validation class with all the validation functions then i accessed these methods via the object of the Validation class .
what happened is that the control was going inside both the conditions

```
if(some cond ..)
System.out.println("inside IF");
else
System.out.println("inside ELSE");
```

I also tried

```
if(some cond ..)
{
System.out.println("inside IF");
}
else
{
System.out.println("inside ELSE");
}
```

in both the cases the control was going inside both the conditions and printing both the lines.
I could not explain this to my self , no matter what condition i give if this is not a syntax error it should only go in either of the loop but not both

CAN ANYBODY EXPLAIN HOW CAN IT BE POSSIBLE THAT BOTH THE IF AND ELSE CONDITIONS BEING EXECUTED ???

I made some other irrelevant changes in my project and after some time it was working fine , but at that time i could not explain my self how it was possible

btw if it matters , i was using this class inside a android project thus android compiler was being used

Comment: If-Else is not a loop.

Comment: can you submit more code? specially the condition?

Comment: it's not possible that if executes both. Maybe you call that method twice and one time it's the if, the other time the else branch

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR : i accept if- else is not loop , my apologies

Comment: @VipulShah : dude its 100 % true but not an issue to make fun of , if anything happens then we find a proper explanation and i guess i had mine with the given answers

Comment: @zapl : i am quite sure the method was called only once , but your approach gives me a logical approach , since i could not reproduce it so i cant make sure , but i am pretty sure i am correct because i was debugging and i saw it happening.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid : It couldnt be true. Both if else ***conditional statements*** executes only one at a time. **if** it is true, then i am surely with VipulShah's statement and **else**, its not an issue.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj : Dude , i also know its not possible , thats why i asked here so that we can get an explanation , the ans below by Dan gives an explanation , i am not saying it an issue , its just that i faced so and couldn't explain , so asked , and fortunately got the most appropriate explanation

Comment: Its good that you got explanation for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean if-else conditional statements, not loops.

It sounds like a threading issue. You probably have a thread that goes on one route, while another one calls the same method and goes on the other path. This is how you can get both strings displayed.

In order to debug this, you could print `Thread.currentThread()` at the end of each `System.out.println` call. I'm sure you will see different `Thread` object addresses.

Answer (score 0):

For googlers end up here; I encountered same situation in java in Android.

in my case (not the exactly same code);

```
int state = 1;
if(state == 1)
{
    //invokes here
    state = 3;
}
else if(state==2){}
else if (state ==3)
{
    //invokes here too
}
```

The issue is that if this is run on an event like "touch"; it may run multiple times. Second invocation of the above code obviously runs the state ==3 part of the code. To avoid this you should use click events or a timer that ignores touch events for a brief time after the first touch.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue of flow.
i had same issue when i used if-else inside a for loop.
actually it was executing the first time it went if block but the second time it went else block because on second time the if condition was not met. Now if you are using if-else inside loop then use break statement